# Is the construct “Strength cannot beat MORE strength without ...” correct?

Tags: american-english, sentence

Is the following quote correct English?

> Strength cannot beat **more** strength without ju jitsu

Comment: Which aspect(s) are you concerned about the correctness of?  The spelling of ju jitsu, or the wording, or the capitalisation, or…?

Comment: I agree with PLL; in a question tagged with _spelling_, and asking if the sentence is correct, I would understand the question is about spelling.

Comment: my bad, I will re-tag it.

Comment: @Dori I was wondering if the quote was correct, thats it. there is nothing more here. it sounded like it was not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote

> Strength cannot beat more strength without ju jitsu

may sound awkwardly phrased to some, but it is correct in every grammatical sense. This is readily apparent if one considers *strength* and *more strength* personified.

Answer (score 8):

Of course not -- there are many martial arts that can do the job ;o).

On a more relevant and grammatical note, this would be more correct:

> Strength cannot beat *greater* strength without Ju Jitsu.

*More* would be appropriate if strength were something that came in units rather than in degree.

Comment: not really. please watch UFC1 and see what I mean. it was proven. your theory is not.

Comment: Note that the term *martial arts* encompasses such things as marksmanship and archery as well as hand-to-hand combat techniques. And there's the fact many hand-to-hand disciplines also involve a code of ethics that would prohibit contests like UFC matches because of the understanding that the surest means of incapacitating an opponent is to kill him.

Comment: @Stan Rogers I disagree about marksmanship and archery. martial arts means hand to hand combat. So to me You are not a martial artist. You are just a hunter or a sportsman.

Comment: Um, no. You may disagree all you want, but history is against you.

Comment: *Martial arts* literally means *arts of war*, and the phrase has been around the English language for a lot longer than Asian-derived hand-to-hand fighting techniques have been with us in the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Stan: According to NOAD, *more* means *a greater or additional amount or degree*. Thus, both *greater strength* and *more strength* are correct. The choice of adjective depends entirely on the writer. There are several instances where *more strength* is found. I daresay that's more common than *greater strength*.

Comment: @Jimi: Not in the sense used here. When describing an attribute, one would normally use "stronger" or "greater strength"; "more strength" would be used more in the sense of "put your back into it" or "it needs more elbow grease". It's subtle, but different.

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically, I think that your statement is fine, but I'd find it easier to understand if you included the subject in the sentence:

> One cannot beat a stronger opponent without ju jitsu.

Comment: its a quote, so I would rather not change it. thx for responce.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, I asked:

> What exactly is the question here? You said that "its [sic] a quote, so I would rather not change it." So if you aren't asking about spelling, and you aren't asking about rephrasing—what are you asking?
>
> And just so you know: in American English, it's almost always spelled *jiu jitsu*.

The OP replied:

> I was wondering if the quote was correct, thats it. there is nothing more here. it sounded like it was not grammatically correct.

Is the quote correct? I can't say for sure, but I can say that there are zero Google hits for that full phrase (other than to *this* page, which I figure doesn't count).

Similar phrases I did find:

- "Strength cannot beat more strength without Gracie Jiu jitsu.."
  —[Twitter/@Dartford BJJ](http://twitter.com/#!/dartfordbjj/statuses/37425541254488064)
- "Brute strength cannot beat amazingness."
  —comment on [Who Is the Strongest Person in the World?](http://fishslapsababy.blogspot.com/2008/02/who-is-strongest-person-in-world.html?showComment=1202792040000#c1614201494643033802)
- "Size and strength cannot beat style and technique"
  —comment on [What Brock's loss means to me...](http://www.mmanews.com/forums/general-mma-forum/45446-what-brocks-loss-means-me-2.html#post767899)
- "Brute strength cannot beat a technical fighter."
  —comment on [Kimbo wants another shot at Sean  Gannon](http://www.sherdog.net/forums/f61/kimbo-wants-another-shot-sean-gannon-706245/index4.html#post19981706)
- "Strength cannot beat superior strength; but, superior skill can beat superior strength."
  —comment on [Yashai Warcraft Discussion Board](http://celticsword.websitetoolbox.com/post/show_single_post?pid=5324799&postcount=4)
- "The best strength cannot beat technique"
  —[Dakota Rehbein's Page](http://www.bjpenn.com/profile/DakotaRehbein)

Overall, there's very few hits for this, so I wouldn't call it a common saying. And it's definitely not a common saying about jiu jitsu.

Comment: its from YouTube video, but I bet the orginal was "Strength cannot beat more strength without Gracie Jiu jitsu.." :) nice find :) its not common, but it sounds cool and right :P its about fedor vs. big foot fight. fedor could have won that fight if he had better technique.